# How are functions called when passing ++

Tags: c, functions

I don't understand what is passed to the function f() when I call it like this.

```
main()
{
  void f(int,int);
  int i=10;
  f(i,i++);
}

void f(int i,int j)
{ printf("%d %d",i,j); }
```

gives me 11 10 .Can somebody explain why its 11?

Comment: Try it and find out :)

Comment: I did that, but I need an explanation

Comment: @nischayn22: Can you post the results and explaint he part you don't understand? Also, have you tried `f(i,++i);` and compared it to `f(i,i++);`?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I did that, it gives me 11 11 in first case and 11 10 in second..But I don't get why the first parameter is 11

Comment: Eu!  Why would you feel compelled to write this sort of thing?

Comment: @ncmathsadist I won't ever write such thing, but some interviewers ask such things, also it is worth knowing :)

Comment: Like John Bode sais, this is undefined. What is happening in your case, is that i++ is evaluated first, which will increase i to 11, before passing i, which is now 11, and 10, which is the old value of i, into f. Could as well have been the other way around, or just outputting some crap, or formatting your disk. Undefined means anything can happen!

Comment: I figured it was some form of insanity under duress.

Comment: There are approximately 42*10^9 threads on Stack Overflow with the topic "why don't I understand what the code does when I write an obfuscated mess of i+++i+i++i+i+i". Look there first.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner ++i is really not helpful, it will not aid a single person in understanding this code. Because not only is this code invoking undefined behavior, but on top of that the order of evaluation of function parameters is unspecified behavior, meaning we don't know if it is the left or the right parameter that gets evaluated first. But then it doesn't matter in this case, since the code is already in la-la-land for invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior is undefined, as follows:

From the C99 standard:

> **6.5 Expressions**
> ...
> 2 Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
>  modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.<sup>72)</sup> Furthermore, the prior value
>   shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.<sup>73)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 72) A floating-point status flag is not an object and can be set more than once within an expression.
> 73) This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
>
> ```
>     i = ++i + 1;
>     a[i++] = i;
> ```
>
> while allowing
>
> ```
>     i = i + 1;
>     a[i] = i;
> ```

We're violating the second sentence of that paragraph; we're *not* just reading the prior value to determine the new value to be stored.

Note that *undefined* doesn't necessarily mean *illegal*.  Undefined simply means that the compiler is free to handle the situation any way it sees fit; any result is considered "correct".  You could very well wind up with the result you expected.  Or not.  The program could crash.  Or not.  Or anything else could happen.

In this case, you will get different results based on platform, compiler, optimization settings, surrounding code, etc.  The reason for *that* is as follows:

> **6.5.2.2 Function calls**
> ...
> 10 The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual arguments, and
>   subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspecified, but there is a sequence point
>    before the actual call.

It is unspecified whether `i` or `i++` is evaluated first; furthermore, it is unspecified whether the side effect of `++` is applied immediately after `i++` is evaluated, as follows:

> **6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators**
> ...
>
> 2 The result of the postfix `++` operator is the value of the operand. After the result is
>    obtained, the value of the operand is incremented. (That is, the value 1 of the appropriate
>   type is added to it.) See the discussions of additive operators and compound assignment
>  for information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects of operations on
> pointers. **The side effect of updating the stored value of the operand shall occur between
> the previous and the next sequence point.**

Emphasis mine.

**Edit**

Changed the wording a bit to make it clear that the behavior is *undefined*.

Comment: Your middle paragraph says unspecified, but your first says undefined. Which is it?

Comment: Since the order of evaluations and side effects are *unspecified*, you will get different results under different circumstances. The behavior is left *undefined* so that compilers aren't required to do anything in particular when they encounter code like that.  This case would be easy enough to detect and issue a diagnostic against, but what about a case like `f(*a, (*b)++);` where both `a` and `b` are set to point to `i`?  In a different translation unit?

Comment: @Pubby Both. If a variable gets a value stored anywhere in an expression, one is not allowed to read the same variable elsewhere in that same expression for any other purposes than to determine the value to store. Since the OP's code did this, it is invoking _undefined_ behavior (meaning anything can happen). But on top of that, the order of evaluation of function parameters is _unspecified_ behavior, meaning that the order of the evaluation will be either left-side or right-side first and the compiler does not need to document or tell us which one that applies.

Answer (score 7):

Because undefined behaviour, that's why. You read the value twice and modify it once with no intervening sequence point, which is a giant pile of illegal. Even if it were not illegal, the compiler has no obligation to evaluate your function arguments in any particular order, or indeed, to even evaluate one fully before evaluating another.

Comment: Is this really UB? I thought it was only UB if it was modified twice without a sequence point. (either way you can't rely on the output)

Comment: It's the order of operations that is undefined.  The compiler can choose to evaluate `i` either before or after `i++`.

Comment: @Pubby: today (C++11) it's called sequenced-before/sequenced-after. The evaluation of the first argument is sequenced neither or after the second. The result is still the same here: UB.

Comment: @Steven: That would be unspecified, not undefined. In particular, it means that `foo(bar(), baz());` is perfectly well defined, but may call either `bar` or `baz` first.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, you're right.

Comment: Which compilers can detect this and issue a warning?

Comment: *Undefined* doesn't mean *illegal*.  *Undefined* simply means that the compiler is free to handle the situation any way it wants to; there is no specific requirement to do *anything*.  It may issue a diagnostic and cease translating the program; it may issue a diagnostic but continue translating the program; it may translate the program without a diagnostic; it may invoke Rogue.  *Illegal* implies something like a constraint violation, for which a diagnostic is required.

Comment: @MSalters It is only unspecified if those two function calls are parameters passed to a third function. If they are operands of the comma operator, the order of evaluation is well-defined (left first then right). I suspect you meant the former, but it isn't obvious in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified and so `11 10` is a correct possible output.